# Logger level is not set

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to switch from simple printing to proper logging.

I want to use two different loggers, the first one displaying information on screen and the other one in a file.

My problem is that even though I set my handler level to DEBUG, messages are only displayed from WARNING.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
def setup_logger(self):

    """

    Configures our logger to save error messages

    """

    # create logger for  'facemovie'

    self.my_logger = logging.getLogger('FileLog')

    # create file handler which logs even debug messages

    fh = logging.FileHandler('log/fm.log')

    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create console handler with a higher log level

    self.console_logger = logging.getLogger('ConsoleLog')

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()

    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)



    # create formatter and add it to the handlers

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    #ch.setFormatter(formatter)



    ##Start logging in file

    self.my_logger.info("######")



    # add the handlers to the logger

    self.my_logger.addHandler(fh)

    self.console_logger.addHandler(ch)



    # DEBUG

    self.console_logger.info("MFCKR")

    self.console_logger.debug("MFCKR")

    self.console_logger.warning("MFCKR")

    self.console_logger.error("MFCKR")

    self.console_logger.critical("MFCKR")

    self.my_logger.info("MFCKR")

    self.my_logger.debug("MFCKR")

    self.my_logger.warning("MFCKR")

    self.my_logger.error("MFCKR")

    self.my_logger.critical("MFCKR")
```

And the output :

```
[jll@jll-VirtualBox:~/Documents/FaceMovie]$ python Facemoviefier.py -i data/inputs/samples -o data/
Selected profile is : frontal_face
MFCKR
MFCKR
MFCKR
Starting Application !
Output #0, avi, to 'data/output.avi':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 652x498, q=2-31, 20780 kb/s, 90k tbn, 5 tbc
FaceMovie exited successfully!
[jll@jll-VirtualBox:~/Documents/FaceMovie]$ cat log/fm.log 
2012-07-15 22:23:24,303 - FileLog - WARNING - MFCKR
2012-07-15 22:23:24,303 - FileLog - ERROR - MFCKR
2012-07-15 22:23:24,303 - FileLog - CRITICAL - MFCKR
```

I red the doc and searched for similar errors on the web, but couldn't find any.

Would you have ideas about the reason why the logger doesn't display DEBUGs and INFOs ?

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Just found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614078/logging-setlevel-how-it-works?rq=1)

Don't know why I didn't find it before.

The whole logger level has to be set, even though the handler also is.
I was not setting up the logger's level, and I guess in this case default is Warning.

Problem solved !

Comment: The usual approach is to set the logger level, and only set the handler level if you need to. The logger level controls generation of events from an application, whereas the handler level acts as a filter for a particular audience (e.g. developers, end-users).

Comment: I must have missed it reading the doc :s. The other issue made me understand it. BTW, I am really glad (and even close to say honored) that you take time to comment :). Thank you!