# Cannot log to stream in Python

Tags: python, string, logging

I want to log to stream of io.StringIO, but end up with empty stream. Here is my code:

```
import logging, io

log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
log_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
log_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.addHandler(log_handler)

logger.info("This is test info log")
print(stream.getvalue())
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
It seems to be working if I replace level with "Warning" like this

```
log_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.warning("This is test info log")
```

It also prints into console for some reason

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534245/python-logging-to-stringio-handler

Comment: Apparently, I needed `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`. One can set level on logger and handler separately. Here is the link: https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial

Comment: Here is useful discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614078/logging-setlevel-how-it-works

Answer (score 1):

Configure the root logger: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`.

Then you can set `log_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to whatever level you wish, it will capture logs to stream accordingly.